# How can I find an item of a specific type in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I find an item of a specific type in an array?

For example: 
I have an array of pets.

```
let pets: [Animal] = [Cat(), Cat(), Fish(), Dog()]
```

How do I find the first item of type Dog?

Comment: Are you looking for the object itself or its array index location? Are your elements structures or classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift it's really easy, use `first(where` method of the array. Like so:

```
let cat = pets.first { $0 is Cat }
```

Or, extended version:

```
let cat = pets.first { (animal) -> Bool in
    return animal is Cat
}
```

The first and second piece of the code does the same thing.

Comment: consider `if let cat`

Comment: Don't forget that in order to access its properties/methods you need to cast it i.e let cat = pets.first { $0 is Cat } as? Cat

Answer (score 0):

A more generic version, and the function looks like this:

```
func findAnimal<T: Animal>(ofType: T.Type) -> Animal? {

    return pets.first {
        guard let t = $0 as? T else {
            return false
        }
        return type(of: t) == ofType
    }
}
```

For example:

```
findAnimal(ofType: Dog.self)
```

will return a dog from the array